# UIPageViewController delay in loading ViewController after viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, viewdidload

I've implemented `UIPageViewController` using this tutorial https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/11/move-uipageviewcontroller-dots/ source code https://github.com/jeffaburt/UIPageViewController-Post

It works all fine but when I integrate it in my project it delays after `viewDidLoad()` in `UIViewController` which contains the `UIPageViewController`.

`viewWillAppear` shows up after a long delay of around 1 minute.

I didn't change anything in the original code.

Can anyone point me what could be wrong? Or how do I go about finding out what is causing the issue?

Here is the code inside viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pageControl.numberOfPages = introductionsPageViewController!.orderedViewControllers.count
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangePageControlValue), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: **but when I integrate it in my project it delays**. So the delay being created within  your project, right ?

Comment: Yes that's right, delay happens when I integrate within my project. It works fine when I run it with code from above example.

Comment: Could you please show us the `ViewDidLoad` method and the methods which are being called inside the `ViewDidLoad` ?

Comment: I've updated my question with code.

Comment: where do you instantiate all those introductionsPageViewController!.orderedViewControllers ?

Comment: It's in the code, if you see the source code on github you will see how it all works. I've done some more experiments. I've literally plugged in example code from above tutorial into my project but still getting same delay as described above. So it seems something is causing it to delay after viewDidLoad when I integrate it in my project. I ran out of ideas on what could be the reason.